# MongoDB | Size of an array of a specific document given by id

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pymongo

I would like to understand how I can get the length (size) of a string array in a specific document that is found by _id passed to it.

For example:

```
document 1
_id: 1234
arr=["a","b","c","d"]

document 2
_id: 5678
arr=["e", "f"]
```

I would like to get the size of 'arr' by passing the _id "5678"
What's would be the easiest way to do that?

Using pymongo

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use a $match for the id and then use [$size](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

Comment: can you give me an example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- `$match` on `_id`
- `$size` to get the array size
- project to keep only the array-size

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=632a373678a49d87828514c7)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"_id": {"$eq": 5678}}},
 {"$project": {"_id": 0, "arr-size": {"$size": "$arr"}}}])
```